# lines with thicker strokes in the middle with SpriteKit

Tags: objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

Any ideas on how can I draw lines like that using SpriteKit? They need to get thicker at the middle and lighter at the edges.

[image]

Comment: Those look like a circle- or diamond-shaped sprite that has been stretched out a lot.

Comment: I was thinking the same, likely could be done with a circle/fill with node being adjusted with xScale or yScale and then rotating appropriately. I believe CGPath has an ellipsis in rect that might achieve this kind of thing as well without the scaling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method adds a line that connects two points to the scene...

```
- (void) addLineFrom:(CGPoint)p1 toPoint:(CGPoint)p2 withColor:(SKColor)color
{    
    CGFloat dx = p2.x - p1.x;
    CGFloat dy = p2.y - p1.y;
    CGFloat angle = atan2(dy, dx);
    CGFloat length = sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);

    SKShapeNode *shape = [SKShapeNode node];
    shape.path = [self diamondWithSize:CGSizeMake(length, 2)];
    shape.lineWidth = 0.125;
    shape.position = CGPointMake(MIN(p1.x, p2.x)+fabs(dx)/2, MIN(p1.y, p2.y)+fabs(dy)/2);
    shape.fillColor = color;
    shape.strokeColor = color;
    shape.zRotation = angle;
    [self addChild:shape];
 }
```

This method creates a diamond-shaped path...

```
- (CGPathRef) diamondWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    UIBezierPath* bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    [bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(-size.width/2, 0)];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(0, -size.height/2)];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(size.width/2, 0)];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(0, size.height/2)];

    [bezierPath closePath];

    return bezierPath.CGPath;

}
```